# how to solve [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.]

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I want to generate a pdf from an xsl template and xml parameters,

the beginning of the template is the next one:

> < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>   < xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" > 
>   < xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"  encoding="UTF-8" />**

and the bebinning of the xml file:

> < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
>   < GenerationReport > 
>       < ValidationResult > 
>           < Result >...

the error that is coming out:

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 1;  Content is not allowed in prolog.
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:244)
>       at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:285)
>       at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
>       at es.gob.signaturereport.tools.XMLUtils.getDocumentImpl(XMLUtils.java:371)
>       at es.gob.signaturereport.tools.XMLUtils.getDocument(XMLUtils.java:233)
>       ... 53 more

Comment: there should be no space between "<" and "?" in the prolog

Answer (score 1):

@joel-m-lamsen is correct that you don't want a space in `<?`.

However, you also don't want a space between `<` and the element name.  Your samples should be (with line-breaks added to avoid scroll bars):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"
    encoding="UTF-8" />
```

and:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<GenerationReport >
  <ValidationResult >
    <Result >...
```

The space before the `>`, `/>`, or `?>` isn't a problem. (Just don't start adding spaces in `/>` or `?>`.)